# How to split composed end of path file?

Tags: python, split, filepath

i have this filepath :

```
     path ='/home/User/Desktop/Shirt_Nike_Red.jpg'
```

And , i want to split the end of the filepath in the following :

```
     Cat = Shirt_Nike 
     Col = Red
```

So these is the code i used to break it down :

```
      path = '/home/User/Desktop/Shirt_Nike_Red.jpg'
      (Cat , Brand , Col) = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split("_")
```

These is the output that i'm getting

```
       Cat 'Shirt'
       Brand 'Nike'
       Col 'Red.jpg'
```

But what i want to get the following :

```
     Cat = 'Shirt_Nike'
     Col = 'Red'
```

Any Suggestion on how to accomplish that would be much appreciated , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Cat, Col = path.rsplit('.',1)[0].split('/')[-1].rsplit("_", 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.rsplit()`

```
Cat, Col = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1].rstrip(".jpg|png").rsplit("_", 1)
```